# How do i store the results from an db(oracle) query as a global variable to be used in a RUN-IF condition in talend?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, store, talend

I have a dbinput component where i am using an select statement as below:

"`select  file_name,file_size from dat_file where file_name  = '"+(String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")+"' order by file_name desc`"

I want to capture the value of `file_name` and `file_size` into global variables and i can use a RUNIF condition to validate if the filename and size are same from the `filelist_1` folder as in db-IGNORE

only if filename and size are different-Then continue with the rest of the PROCESSING in talend.

Btw,i am getting the file size from tfileproperties component and checking if they are the same in database and the local file folder/dir ,and only if it DIFFERS-continue processing!

My job flow looks like this:
[image: Job flow components]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is comparing FileName from tFileList with FileName from your DB.  To achieve what you want, I think you should also compare FileSize in this query. Then you can check in a RUNIF condition the number of lines in your tDBInput (using global variable tDBInput_2_NB_LINE) If 0 then you don't have a match and you can continue the process

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing a wonderful tip,really appreciate it...you're the best...but was contemplating if there is any way to store the value from the select statement(dbinput2) for eg.filename and filesize into a  global variable so i could use them in the downstream components be it tjava or few components down the line?

Comment: I would want to see the value getting used in some other component from tdbinput2 besides tlogrow...coz i cant seem to find a way to store and retrieve the value especially after querying the database!

Comment: try to put tDBInput-->tJavaRow . In tJava row : globalMap.put("filename",input_row.filename);    then you can call your global Variable using ((String)globalMap.get("filename"))  everywhere in your job

Comment: I have tried several approaches and scourged the internet to find a better solution,but none of them are what i expect it to be,Please find the link to my question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64258690/how-to-just-extract-the-last-2-days-recent-files-from-tftpfilelist-based-on-modi
Basically i would need to find the last 2 days worth of files from the remote ftp site in a faster and effective way,tjava code is not suffice since the filename has so many fields in it

Comment: Added the java code as well,please take a look and suggest what am i missing there?@corentin