# how to just extract the last 2 days recent files from tftpfilelist based on modified time without storing in a tbufferoutput component-talend job

Tags: java, talend, jobs

As of now i am iterating through all the 5k files available in the folder and store them in a tbufferoutput and read through them by using tbufferinput and sorting them based on mtime desc(modified time in the ftp site) in the descending order and extract the top 10 files only.

Since its iterating through all the 5k files at once its time consuming and causing unnecessary latency issues with the remote ftp site.

i was wondering if there is any other simple way without iterating just get the latest top 10 files from the ftp site directly and sort them based on mtime desc and perform operations with them?

My talend job flow looks like this at the moment,would advise any other methods that could optimize the performance of the job in a much better way!
[image]

Basically i dont want to iterate and run through all the files in the ftp site,instead directly get the top 10 from the remote ftp :tftpfilelist  and perform checks in db and download them later

IS THERE ANYWAY WITHOUT ITERATING ,CAN I JUST GET THE LATEST 10 FILES just by using modified timestamp in desc order alone?-This is the question in short
OR
I want to extract the LAST 3 days files from the remote ftp site.

Filename is in this format:A_B_C_D_E_20200926053617.csv

Approach B:WITH JAVA,
I tried using the tjava code as below: for the flow B:

```
Date lastModifiedDate = TalendDate.parseDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", row2.mtime_string);

Date current_date = TalendDate.getCurrentDate();

System.out.println(lastModifiedDate);

System.out.println(current_date);
System.out.println(((String)globalMap.get("tFTPFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")));

if(TalendDate.diffDate(current_date, lastModifiedDate,"dd") <= 1) {

System.out.println

output_row.abs_path = input_row.abs_path;

System.out.println(output_row.abs_path);
}
```

Now the tlogrow3 is printing NULL values all over,please suggest
[image]

Comment: since you have the date in the filename, maybe you can create 3 file masks for the 3 days and use them in the tFTPFileList to retrieve only those files.

Comment: no,that wont work because for a particular day we may receive n number of files and also the timestamp (hhmmss) could vary since we receive so many files in a day and this has to be automated,so i cannot keep hardcoding the values on every job run

Comment: No need to hardcode anything, you compute a mask with wildcards  for a date (today or yesterday) and the 2 dates before, ex.  `*20200926*.csv  *20200925*.csv *20200924*.csv`, put them in context or globalMap and use them in the tFTPFileList.

Comment: Yes,i get you but how do i dynamically keep changing the date range going forward ,lets say next week the dates would be entirely different and also everyday this job runs periodically every once or twice in a day.in that case i cannot really compute a filemask and append to context or globalMap

Comment: See my answer for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define 3 context variables :

[image]

in tJava, compute the mask (with wildcard) for the 3 days (starting at the current date) :

```
Date currentDate = TalendDate.getCurrentDate();
Date currentDateMinus1 = TalendDate.addDate(currentDate, -1, "dd");
Date currentDateMinus2 = TalendDate.addDate(currentDate, -2, "dd");

context.mask1 ="*" + TalendDate.formatDate("yyyyMMdd", currentDate) + "*.csv";
context.mask2 ="*" + TalendDate.formatDate("yyyyMMdd", currentDateMinus1) + "*.csv";
context.mask3 ="*" + TalendDate.formatDate("yyyyMMdd", currentDateMinus2) + "*.csv";
```

then in the tFTPFileList, use the 3 context variables for filemask :

[image]

to retrieve the files only from today and the 2 previous day.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution,it really helps ,i was also looking at a way where if i want to tweak it lets say 5+ days for some of the files,if there was  a method by which i could just change one parameter and make it work.Anyways thanks for the input ,i will try to advance more on this :)

Comment: @Tommy  you can mark this answer as accepted then open another question if required, thanks.